# Create a file in GitHub action

Tags: security, containers, github-actions

Inside Github Action I'm using Anchore+grype to scan a container image, using the job below:

```yaml
name: "CI"
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  image-analysis:
    name: Analyze image
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Scan operator image
        uses: anchore/scan-action@v3
        id: scan
        with:
          image: "qserv/qserv-operator:2022.1.1-rc1"
          acs-report-enable: true
```

In order to ignore a false-positive during image scan, I want to create the file `$HOME/.grype.yaml` (see content below) before launching the image scan:

```yaml
ignore:

  # False positive, see https://github.com/anchore/grype/issues/558
  - vulnerability: CVE-2015-5237
    fix-state: unknown
    package:
      name: google.golang.org/protobuf
      version: v1.26.0
      type: go-module
      location: "/manager"
```

Could you please show me how to create this file inside Github Action?

Comment: Hey, small doubt. Is there any specific need as to why you need this? Would it not be favourable to create the yaml in the repo itself and provide that file in the github actions instead of everytime trying to create and add details inside the github actions?

Comment: Interesting idea! But the `.grype.yaml` file need to be in `$HOME`, not in the source code.

Comment: I just checked their source repo [README](https://github.com/anchore/scan-action#additional-configuration), they mention this config file can be in the repository root itself. I don't know much about this action, but am I missing something?

Comment: @iambk could you please add a link to this part of the doc? I was not able to find it

Answer (score 2):

you could do something as simple as creating the file and then writing to it like this:

```
    - name: Create grype.yaml
      run: |
           touch grype.yaml
           echo "
           ignore:
               # False positive, see https://github.com/anchore/grype/issues/558
               - vulnerability: CVE-2015-5237
               fix-state: unknown
               package:
                 name: google.golang.org/protobuf
                 version: v1.26.0
                 type: go-module
                 location: "/manager"" > ~/grype.yaml
```

Comment: It is not enough, I need to fill the file with the yaml content above.

Comment: ok, in that case you can write the contents to the file using `echo`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! In order to be accurante, don't you have to escape quotes around `/manager` and remove the first blank line?

Comment: In addtion, there is too much whitespaces at the beginning of each line...

Comment: could be, and for that there are bunch of yaml formatting tools you can use in your GHA. For. e.g. https://github.com/credfeto/action-yaml-format

Comment: Maybe using cat+EOF might be an interesting alternative?

Answer (score 0):

This one works and has been tested successfully on Github Actions:

```
name: "CI"
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  image-analysis:
    name: Analyze image
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    permissions:
      security-events: write
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Create grype configuration
        run: |
          cat <<EOF > $HOME/.grype.yaml
          ignore:
            # False positive, see https://github.com/anchore/grype/issues/558
            - vulnerability: CVE-2015-5237
              fix-state: unknown
              package:
                name: google.golang.org/protobuf
                version: v1.26.0
                type: go-module
                location: "/manager"
          EOF
      - name: Scan operator image
        uses: anchore/scan-action@v3
        id: scan
        with:
          image: ""qserv/qserv-operator:2022.1.1-rc1""
          acs-report-enable: true
          fail-build: false
```